# how do i get an Array from another class?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am trying to parse an array from 1 class to another, but i couldnt to manage to do it.

I am trying to pass the array that is selected from 1st Class file to the second. What is happening in the 1st class file is as follows : 1.) List of array are split and put into boxes 2.) Box is clicked and that specific group of array is selected 3.) That array is then send over/retrieve from the 2nd Class file.

At the moment i can select and trace the group of array elements that are selected, but not sure how to transfer them to the next class.

```
function gotoscene(e: MouseEvent):void{

        var searchString = listings;
             var index:Number;

            index = searchString.indexOf(e.target);

        trace (test[index].nobed,test[index].zip,test[index].Location,test[index].price);



            while(_contentHolder.numChildren > 0)
           {
_contentHolder.removeChildAt(0);

       }
```

Thanks for your time!

Edit:
adding a

```
public var somedata:String;

     function gotoscene(e: MouseEvent):void{

        var searchString = listings;
             var index:Number;

            index = searchString.indexOf(e.target);

        somedata = test[index].nobed,test[index].zip,test[index].Location,test[index].price;

var list :Listingdetailinfo = new Listingdetailinfo(somedata);
```

Class 2

```
        public function Listingdetailinfo(initdata:Array) {


            somedata=initdata;


                trace(initdata);

}
```

Comment: Provide more accurate code, as 'test' is not declared and there is no passing to second class. Obviously, this code is absolutely not useful.

Answer (score 0):

How are you initializing each class? 
You could make the array you are trying to access in class 1 from class 2 a public var and use a getter method on that array from class 2.

**Edit:**
So is it safe to assume that Listingdetailinfo is your Class2? I noticed that you're missing the } for the gotoscene function, not sure that matters as this is just a snippet of your code. When does the gotoscene function get called. Right now it appears nothing is calling that function and there for your array is getting passed into class 2 before its defined.

Comment: I think i managed to make it work using by reference, with the array. Still working on it, but i edited the code above

Comment: 1 very weird thing is that the class 2 is imported into class 3, and the data is from class 1 to class 2. Now that it traces the correct array, but nothing would display. I will have to try to figure out why.